# Subtract Rows of Matrix from rows of another matrix numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrix V_r of shape(19, 300) and vecs of shape(100000, 300). I would like to subtract rows of V_r from from rows of vecs. Currently, I am achieving this with the following code. Is there a way to do it using broadcasting?

```
    list=[]
for v in V_r:
    a=np.linalg.norm(vecs-v,axis=1)
    list.append(a)
M=np.vstack(list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you're looking for :  `np.linalg.norm(vecs-V_r[:,np.newaxis], axis = 2)`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
np.linalg.norm(vecs[:, :, None] - V_r[None, :, :].transpose(0, 2, 1), axis=1)
```